# dynamically build javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins

I'm trying to make a Javascript object from a JSON object. This because I want to make a graph with a .js plugin who needs a special set of data. He needs the following object as data:

```
var data = {
labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
    },
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
    }
] }
```

and my JSON object looks like this (don't mind the data, it's test data). There are no problems with my JSON object. It has passed some JSON validators online:

```
{ "Metingen": [
    {
        "Temp": "25.00",
        "Humy": "37.40",
        "Time": [
            {
                "Uur": "22",
                "Minuut": "32",
                "Second": "15",
                "Dag": "15",
                "Maand": "06",
                "Jaar": "2014"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Temp": "25.00",
        "Humy": "37.20",
        "Time": [
            {
                "Uur": "22",
                "Minuut": "32",
                "Second": "15",
                "Dag": "15",
                "Maand": "06",
                "Jaar": "2014"
            }
        ]
    } ] }
```

So I will need to put in Labels all the "Dag" values, datasets[0].data needs the "Temp" and datasets[1](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/).data needs the "Humy" values from my JSON object. But how can I do that dynamicly? Because the number of Temp and Humy value can change with every page refresh. I have tried this but that doesn't work. (I have left out the Humy dataset to simplify it here.

```
var dataBuilder = new Object();

for(i = 0; i < objs.Lijnen;i++) {
    dataBuilder.labels[i] = objs.Metingen[i].Time[0].Dag;
    dataBuilder.datasets[0].data[i] = objs.Metingen[i].Temp;
} 
dataBuilder.datasets[0].fillColor = "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)";
dataBuilder.datasets[0].strokeColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)";
dataBuilder.datasets[0].pointColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)";
dataBuilder.datasets[0].pointStrokeColor = "#fff";
```

But then I get a "Cannot set Property '0' of undefined" on line 4. 
I also tried the following things:

```
for(i = 0; i < objs.Lijnen;i++) {
    dataBuilder[labels][i] = objs.Metingen[i].Time[0].Dag;
    dataBuilder[datasets][0][data][i] = objs.Metingen[i].Temp;
} ... (code omitted)
```

I read somewhere that Javascript objects are just arrays of arrays but this is logic it doesn't work because "labels", "datasets" and "data" are undefined. So I tried this one as well:

```
for(i = 0; i < objs.Lijnen;i++) {
    dataBuilder["labels"][i] = objs.Metingen[i].Time[0].Dag;
    dataBuilder["datasets"][0]["data"][i] = objs.Metingen[i].Temp;
} (code omitted)
```

But here I get as well a bad error. I have checked objs.Metingen[i].Time[0].Dag and objs.Metingen[i].Temp and they work perfect. So anyone got an idea how I can parse my JSON data to the datastyle I need for the Graph plugin? Maybe JQuery? (More info over the [Graph plugin is here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)) Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your first code:

1. The object dataBuilder is not properly initialized, considering the way you used it later. Consider this code which also causes "Cannot set property '0' of undefined":

   ```
   obj = Object();
   obj.array[0] = 1000;
   ```

   In the above, obj is indeed an object and it can have a property named "array", but that property does not yet exist - therefore, you cannot assign anything to its '0' member (because it is not yet an array at that point, it is "undefined"). Proper example:

   ```
   obj = Object();
   obj.array = Array();
   obj.array[0] = 1000;
   ```

   Or, simpler:

   ```
   obj = {array: []};
   obj.array[0] = 1000;
   ```

   This creates an object with a property "array" that is an empty array.
2. Assuming objs.Lijnen is an object, "i < objs.Lijnen" is always false. What you (may) want is either "objs.Lijnen.Metingen.length" or "objs.Metingen.length" (not really sure if objs.Lijnen is a typo or the parent object for Metingen).
3. Assuming Lijnen is not a typo and it is parent to Metingen, you need to change objs.Metingen to objs.Lijnen.Metingen.

Working code:

```
var obj = {Lijnen: JSON.parse(YOUR_JSON_STRING) };

...

var dataBuilder = {labels: [], datasets: []}; // properly initialized object

for(i = 0; i < objs.Lijnen.Metingen.length;i++) { // .length
    dataBuilder.labels[i] = objs.Lijnen.Metingen[i].Time[0].Dag;
    if (!dataBuilder.datasets[0]) dataBuilder.datasets[0] = { data: [] };
    dataBuilder.datasets[0].data[i] = objs.Lijnen.Metingen[i].Temp;
}
dataBuilder.datasets[0].fillColor = "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)";
dataBuilder.datasets[0].strokeColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)";
dataBuilder.datasets[0].pointColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)";
dataBuilder.datasets[0].pointStrokeColor = "#fff";
```

Comment: Oke, got it working now, I just changed the "var dataBuilder ..." line to yours and now the data is parser without problem!!

Comment: Quick question, what about when I want more then 1 datasets? Because when I call datasets[1] I get the same error.

Comment: I've edited the code to allocate the data array when you first use it in the "if" line above